# Problem during compilation of ROS INDIGO on ARM/Ubuntu trusty from source

Tags: robotic-arm, ros, jetson

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Trying to compile ROS from source on Ubuntu 14 (trusty) on NVIDIA Jetson tk1.
I'm stucked on this problem:

```
==> Processing catkin package: 'qt_gui_cpp'
==> Building with env: '/home/ubuntu/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/env.sh'
Makefile exists, skipping explicit cmake invocation...
==> make cmake_check_build_system in '/home/ubuntu/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/qt_gui_cpp'
==> make -j1 -l1 in '/home/ubuntu/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/qt_gui_cpp'
[ 76%] Built target qt_gui_cpp
[ 84%] Running SIP generator for qt_gui_cpp_sip Python bindings...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/share/python_qt_binding/cmake/sip_configure.py", line 41, in <module>
    subprocess.check_call(cmd)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 535, in check_call
    retcode = call(*popenargs, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 522, in call
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1327, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
make[2]: *** [sip/qt_gui_cpp_sip/Makefile] Error 1
make[1]: *** [src/qt_gui_cpp_sip/CMakeFiles/libqt_gui_cpp_sip.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
<== Failed to process package 'qt_gui_cpp': 
  Command '/home/ubuntu/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/env.sh make -j1 -l1' returned non-zero exit status 2

Reproduce this error by running:
==> cd /home/ubuntu/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/qt_gui_cpp && /home/ubuntu/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/env.sh make -j1 -l1

Command failed, exiting.
```

ANY IDEA?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/187851/problem-during-compilation-of-ros-indigo-on-arm/ubuntu-trusty-from-source/) by [formica](https://answers.ros.org/users/11346/formica/) on ROS Answers with karma: 61 on 2014-07-25

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jacksonkr_](https://answers.ros.org/users/21619/jacksonkr_/) on 2016-04-08**:
Make sure you have `multiverse` and `universe` sources available. Check out my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

**UPDATE**

I now have experimental binary builds of Indigo available for Trusty armhf: http://wiki.ros.org/indigo/Installation/UbuntuARM

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

On my Jetson tk1, this executes /usr/bin/sip, which is part of the sip-dev package. Do you have sip-dev installed?

I found out which executable it's trying to run by reading the sip_configure.py script and then running the following python snippet:

```
from PyQt4 import pyqtconfig
cfg = pyqtconfig.Configuration()
print cfg.sip_bin
```

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-07-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1